# Trying to delete cell contents from the cell that the VBA custom function is in

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete cell contents from the cell that the VBA custom function is in. I have this code however this returns an error:

```
Function test() As Variant
    Application.Caller.ClearContents
End Function
```

Comment: A function called from a sheet cannot do anything but return a value to that same cell that calls the function.

Comment: it hurts my head to even begin to think of how what you want to do would even be possible. It's like trying to erase yourself with yourself! (insert sideways laughing emoji)

Comment: So let me get this straight...you're trying to create a function which clears the contents of the cell containing the function? Putting the clarity of purpose aside for a moment, maybe you could create a worksheet event that automatically clears the cell of interest?

Comment: I would think that instead of entering a UDF, just pressing the DEL key would be far more effective and accomplish the same thing...

Comment: Would probably help to explain the eventual goal once you got this working...

Comment: Listen guys, I have an if statement in Excel which is supposed to return nothing if a certain condition is met. For this I used this: "" but Excel unfortunately does not recognize it as a blank cell. This is when I called my friend VBA to solve the problem however as you can see it doesn't work. Now with the purpose in mind can you please help my problem.

Comment: What is the IF formula pointing at (another formula, a manual entry) ?  You could use an event handler to populate the IF cell instead of a formula.  Or take another approach to determining what is a "blank" cell (you don't say how you're determining blanks)

Comment: For me a blank cell is a cell that the ISBLANK() function  returns true.

Comment: @Victor Is there a reason you are not able to share with us your current If formula? That would help very much to solve your problem. Write the formula out and give us discrete examples of the arguments and conditions.

Comment: So when your if formula returns nothing in a cell (using quotes), the isblank formula sees that as a non-empty cell? The isblank formula doesn't work that way...it looks at cell contents, and if the target cell contains an if formula, then it has contents.

Comment: Instead of using isblank, just use the equality test A1="", which will return TRUE if the value in A1 is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Given A1 contains an If formula that returns nothing when a certain condition is met, entering the following in B1 will indicate that the formula in A1 returned nothing...

```
=A1=""
```

Used in a subsequent if formula...

```
=if(A1="","action if A1 is blank","action if it isn't")
```